# Alignment (offset - shifting) arrays with multiplication and addition

Tags: c, arrays, function

I have two arrays and I want to multiply them and then add the results to form an output array. But I need to shift the first array to where its center overlaps with the top-left element of the second array and then multiply and add up the result and put it in the first element of the output array. And then repeat the process for all elements. 
The picture in the link explains what I mean:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B21Hup_IhGDddmFJRDZZaWR3QUE

I tried a specific answer for specific elements for the arrays just to get the idea first, but I need to apply the idea for any two arrays!

My code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define XKERN 3
#define YKERN 3
#define XMAX 3
#define YMAX 4

int main(void) {
    int input[XMAX][YMAX] = {{1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};
    int fkern[XKERN][YKERN] = {{3,2,1},{0,0,0},{-3,-2,-1}};
    int output[XMAX][YMAX];
    int ofsx,ofsy,total,fkx,fky,i,j,ix,jy;
    for(i=0;i< XMAX;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j< YMAX;j++,total=0)  
        {
            ofsx=i;
            ofsy=j;
            for(jy=0,fky=0;jy< YMAX||fky< YKERN;jy++,fky++ )
            {
                for(ix=0,fkx=0;ix< XMAX||fkx< XKERN;ix++,fkx++)
                {
                    if((ofsx-ix)>=-1 && (ofsx-ix)<=1 &&  \
                        (ofsy-jy)>=-1 && (ofsy-jy)<=1 && \
                        ((ofsx+fkx)-1)>=0 && ((ofsx+fkx)-1)<=XMAX && \
                        ((ofsy+fky)-1)>=0 && ((ofsy+fky)-1)<=YMAX)

                    {
                        total=total+(input[ix][jy]*fkern[fkx][fky]);
                    }
                 }
                 output[i][j]=total;
                 printf("[%d][%d]=%d\n",i,j,output[i][j]);
             }
         }

     return 0;
 }
```

I would really appreciate it if you help me.

Comment: And what is the problem with the code you show? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Additionally, StackOverflow allows you to add pictures to questions. You are more likely to get good answers if you add the picture here instead of just linking to it - you can do this by **editing** your question.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot add pictures right now !

Comment: the problem with my code that its only for particular two arrays

Comment: Also, the code you have included is missing a closing brace for the first `for`.

Comment: yeah I just noticed that , sorry for that @Toby